# Improving Heat dissipation in freezer

Tags: safety, freezing

I have a small apartment and a large freezer; I'm concerned about heat build up in and around the freezer.

I have a similar problem with an old PC tower, to which my solution was to create and external radiator from empty coke cans and fix it to the exterior of the computer case. It's worked very well and the always-on PC is as cool as can be.

My question is, besides warranty issues, is there any reason I couldn't/shouldn't make another external radiator, and use crocodile clips to fix it to the grounding and the internal heat dissipator?

Comment: You haven't said *why* you're concerned. Is there some indication of a problem?

Comment: Have you left *at least* the manufacturer's recommended space around the freezer and made sure that the ambient temperature is within the specified allowable range? If so, then you have done enough. Poking around the freezer's radiator could end up with the refrigerant leaking, which is not good.

Comment: i have done so. HIstory tells me, however, that this will not last. Unless I fill the space around it with something like a radiator.

Comment: i dropped my tightly-installed fridge's duty cycle ~25% using an 80mm computer case fan (at 5v instead of 12v for silence) to push air under the fridge (where the air intake for the coils is). if you have any warm pockets around the fridge, you will save money doing the same. the fridge's coils are designed to cool with air, so just add more air to get better cooling, no mods needed.